# Kinesis Firehose access denied on source record and output s3 bucket is empty

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to learn how to use Kinesis Firehose.  I am using a basic sample application.  The source record is saying Access Denied and the S3 output bucket is empty.  From the [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/troubleshooting.html#data-not-delivered-to-s3) I have verified that the IncomingBytes and IncomingRecords graphs have data but the DeliveryToS3 Success is blank.  I am Debugging a .NET console application locally with Visual Studio 2017.  The credentials I am using are able to run the basic AWS sample project, listing EC2 instances, SimpleDB and S3 buckets.  I'm wondering if these keys don't have access to Firehose, though.

Here is my C# code:

```
                var kClient = new KinesisFirehoseClient(AwsRegion.USEast1, new AwsCredential("***********", "************"));
                var deliveryStreamName = "testeventspoc";
                var deliveryStream = kClient.GetStream(deliveryStreamName);
                sr.WriteLine($"Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream: {deliveryStream.Name}");

                PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest(deliveryStreamName,new Record(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{\"ticker_symbol\":\"QXZ\", \"sector\":\"HEALTHCARE\", \"change\":\"-0.05\", \"price\":\"84.51\"}")));


                // Put record into the DeliveryStream
                var resultOfRecord = kClient.PutRecordAsync(putRecordRequest).Result;
```

And here is the source record:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>A0xxxxxx</RequestId>
    <HostId>sP**********kfc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

So......how can I fix this and/or how can I troubleshoot this further?  At this point, I'm taking stabs in the dark and trying random stuff since AWS's documentation in this area seems woefully lacking.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you [Grant Kinesis Data Firehose Access to an Amazon S3 Destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#using-iam-s3)?

Comment: Yes, the wizard added just enough rights and I followed up by giving it full rights.  I figured out part of my problem.  The access denied was just through the browser.  I apparently can see the listing of the item in the aws console but not view it in a browser.  Using the AWS ToolKit for Visual Studio 2017, I was able to view the contents of the source and destination buckets.  Both now actually have the data, so that solves most of my problem.  The other issue I am seeing is that the items seem to get batched up, then spit out in one giant object in S3, eventually. Can I speed that up?

Comment: You can configure Amazon Kinesis Firehose to output a batch based on duration (60 to 900 seconds) or data size (1-128 MB), whichever is met first.

Comment: @DanCsharpster Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Jeremy, which part are you asking about?  I'm assuming you mean the last part since most of the other solutions to my problem are addressed in the comment thread.  Its been a minute but from what I remember, based on [Frequency docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-deliver.html#frequency) that John eluded to, I was able to find [configuration instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-configure.html) that let me shrink the batch size and see results sooner.